# Wordpress pagination is not updating content

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am working with a theme that has pagination on the home page for the blog posts. When I click on pg2 (or any page link) it refreshes but shows pg1 content. Is there something missing from the code below that keeps it from working correctly?

```
            <?php
            $makenzie_lite_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'paged' => $paged,
                'category_name' => 'blogPost'
            );

            $makenzie_lite_query = new WP_Query( $makenzie_lite_args );

            if ( $makenzie_lite_query->have_posts() ) :

                // amount of pages
                $makenzie_lite_num_pages = $makenzie_lite_query->max_num_pages;

                /* Start the Loop */
                while ( $makenzie_lite_query->have_posts() ) : $makenzie_lite_query->the_post();

                $makenzie_lite_layout = makenzie_lite_get_theme_mod( 'posts_style_template', 'post-s1' );

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/listing/' . $makenzie_lite_layout );

                endwhile;
            else :
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
            endif;

            // reset query
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

EDIT:
I added this code I found on another SE post:

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}
```

and it works, but now the page numbers just expand as I click thru the pages. Go to ameliaislander.com to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_query_var` like this:

```php
$makenzie_lite_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
    'category_name' => 'blogPost'
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that did not fix the problem.